# XML: How to grab all text nodes and nodes between 2 processing instructions with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<p>
    <?PI start?> Grab <span>all</span> these <span>text</span> nodes <?PI end?>
</p>
```

With the XML above, I am try to grab all the content in the middle of the two PI's and wrap them in a  element, is there a way to achieve this in XSLT?

My desired output is:

```
<p>
    <?PI start?><u> Grab <span>all</span> these <span>text</span> nodes </u><?PI end?>
</p>
```

Comment: It is possible, how you do it depends on the version of XSLT/XPath supported and of course on the input, if you want to do that for that simple case with two processing instruction as siblings in the same parent you can use the `<<` and/or `>>` operator in XPath 2. In a more complex setting in XSLT 2 it is usually possible to solve such problems with nested `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with. In XSLT 1 a key or sibling recursion are ways, more difficult to write, more difficult to adapt to complex settings, but doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0**: best to write a recursive template that starts at the first PI and calls itself recursively to processing following-sibling::node()[1] until the end PI is encountered.

**XSLT 2.0**: bind variables $s and $e to the two processing instructions, then use

```
p/*[. >> $s and . << $e]
```

**XSLT 3.0**: consider `xsl:iterate`:

```
<xsl:iterate select="p/processing-instruction(PI)[.='start']/following-sibling::node()">
   <xsl:if test="self::processing-instruction(PI)[.='end']">
      <xsl:break/>
   </xsl:if>
   ...
</xsl:iterate>
```

**Saxon:**

```
p/* => saxon:items-after(.{processing-instruction(PI)[.='start']})
    => saxon:items-before(.{processing-instruction(PI)[.='end']})
```

Comment: `p/*[. >> $s and . << $e]` should be `p/node()[. >> $s and . << $e]` I think to select the text child nodes like ` Grab ` in the sample as well.